# jQuery validation and jQuery Mobile select list conflicts

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

First i'm using ASP.Net MVC4 and latest jQuery 2.0.3, jQuery mobile 1.3.1, jQuery UI 1.10.3 and jQuery Unobstrusive Validation Plugin 1.11.1

I got a probleme with jQuery validation.. it confounds the display text of the select list and the error message...

So jQuery validate adds the class "input-validation-error" to this html element when error occurs.. My problem is that when i choose a valid value and submit (with other errors in the form) jquery adds a style="display:none" to this span ! So my select list appears like nothing was selected...

The span element concerned :

```
<span>Select a card</span>
```

The Html code below is generated with :

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardType)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardType, Model.CardList)
```

and the submit button :

```
<button type="submit" data-transition="flip" data-theme="e" data-role="button">Buy</button>
```

Here is an exemple :

Initial state of generated select list :

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">
                <span>Select a card</span>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        <select data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a payment card" id="CardType" name="CardType">
            <option value="">Select a card</option>
            <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="AmericanExpress">American Express</option>
            <option value="MasterCardPrepago">MasterCard Prepago</option>
            <option value="EuroCardMasterCard">EuroCard / MasterCard</option>
            <option value="CarteBleue">Carte bleue nationale</option>
            <option value="VisaDebit">Visa Debit</option>
            <option value="VisaElectron">Visa Electron</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how do i say to jquery validate to not use the span created by jquery mobile as an error field ?!

Thanks

Comment: A little hint, use jquery 1.9.1 not 2.0.x.

Comment: I prefer to not downgrade my jquery version.. What problems are known using jquery 2.0.x ??

Answer (score 0):

I found a little help in another post i made on the jquery forums (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/conflict-with-jquery-validate)

> http://api.jquerymobile.com
>
> jQuery Mobile 1.3 supports jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.9.1
>
> Further, while the jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI teams are working
>   toward compatibility (in 1.4 and later), jQuery Mobile is *not*
>   compatible with jQuery UI. They weren't designed to be compatible.
>   Some developers have gotten some functionality to work together, or
>   have gotten some third-party plugins to work. (And there are some
>   jQuery UI plugins that are explicitly designed to work with both
>   jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile - for example, jquery.ui.maps comes to
>   mind) it almost always will take some modification or trickery.
>
> You will at least have to resolve the CSS conflicts between jQuery UI
>   and jQuery Mobile, which means you will have to use a seldom-used
>   feature to add a prefix to all of your jQuery Mobile CSS.

So decided to use CSS to fix this, and the solution is really simple as :

```
.ui-select .input-validation-error { display: block !important;}
```

Done!